# cuda10.1 installation Error _installation_

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch

i remove cuda 10.1 but torch.cuda.is_available() still return True.
what is the problem ?
and when i import scatter_cuda it give :
ImportError: No module named 'torch_scatter.scatter_cuda'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I get the response , it must that i install torch_scatter after i configure the cuda $PATH and $CPATH then install torch_scatter because it need to get a 'C' compiled file ( scatter cuda ) compatible with my GPU and my Cuda version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).